# Getting the vector points of a letter in a truetype font

Tags: c++, winapi, fonts

Since True Type fonts are just vectors, I was wondering if there was a way to get the vectors (array of points) for a letter given that i'm using the WinAPI.
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the GetGlyphOutline function with the GGO_NATIVE option.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144891%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Actually, True Type fonts are defined by Bezier curves, not vectors, so you get back a list of curves. Most graphics libraries have a way of drawing Bezier curves anyway so you can get by just knowing that a curve is defined by several control points.

The font will be pre-fitted to a grid (eg, hinting).

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if the Win32 API will give you a deconstructed glyph. The FOSS FreeType2 library provides glyph points in `FT_Outline::points`.

Note that a glyph is more than its points. You have to work with Bézier curves and hinting to reproduce a glyph correctly. The hinting part is crucial for small fonts, and is extremely difficult to get right. FreeType usually does all this for you.

Comment: Can you suggest how to use the `FreeType` `python` binding for this particular purpose? Also in what kind of coordinate system are these points returned?

Comment: I checked out the Python binding docs, there was no clear usage info nor details of what data is returned

Comment: `import freetype; f = freetype.Face("…Arial.ttf"); f.set_char_size(48 * 64); f.load_char("G"); print f.glyph.outline.points`